# How to get the status of a travis-ci request

Tags: travis-ci

I want to trigger a travis run on the master branch of a repository. That works alright following the instructions in the [travis docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/triggering-builds), but then I don't know how to get the status of the execution. The request returns some IDs, but none seem to be the request id.

```
$ body='{
"request": {
  "branch":"master"
}}'

$ curl -s -X POST   -H "Content-Type: application/json"   -H "Accept: application/json"   -H "Travis-API-Version: 3"   -H "Authorization: token $TOKEN"   -d "$body"   https://api.travis-ci.org/repo/snapcore%2Fsnapcraft/requests                                                                                                           
{
  "@type": "pending",
  "remaining_requests": 9,
  "repository": {
    "@type": "repository",
    "@href": "/repo/6402925",
    "@representation": "minimal",
    "id": 6402925,
    "name": "snapcraft",
    "slug": "snapcore/snapcraft"
  },
  "request": {
    "repository": {
      "id": 45199136,
      "owner_name": "snapcore",
      "name": "snapcraft"
    },
    "user": {
      "id": 38186
    },
    "message": null,
    "branch": "master",
    "config": {
    }
  },
  "resource_type": "request"
}
```

I can get all the requests using this endpoint: https://docs.travis-ci.com/api?http#requests
But then I would have to find my request, and again I'm not sure how to identify it.

Answer (score 0):

The response should include a `request.id` as well:

```
{
  "@type": "pending",
  "remaining_requests": 49,
  "repository": {
    "@type": "repository",
    "@href": "/repo/7181875",
    "@representation": "minimal",
    "id": 7181875,
    "name": "repo_name",
    "slug": "repo_user/repo_name"
  },
  "request": {
    "repository": {
      "id": 160982756,
      "owner_name": "repo_owner",
      "name": "repo_name"
    },
    "user": {
      "id": 919859
    },
    "id": 160105240,   # <-- this is the request ID that can be used in /request/#id
    "message": null,
    "branch": "master",
    "config": {
    }
  },
  "resource_type": "request"
}
```

This seems to be missing from what you posted. Either this was added in the meantime, or it got lost for you somehow.